# Python Aiogram: при нажатии на инлайн-кнопку URL в Telagram Bot пользователю присылается сообщение: "Вы нажали на ссылку"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данный код:

Python Aiogram: при нажатии на инлайн-кнопку URL в Telagram Bot пользователю присылается сообщение: "Вы нажали на ссылку"

[image: Python Aiogram: при нажатии на инлайн-кнопку URL в Telagram Bot пользователю присылается сообщение: "Вы нажали на ссылку"]

Answer (score 0):

Не поленитесь в будущем поискать ответ самому, так как вам это поможет научиться писать код самостоятельно. Такого рода вариант решения гуглится без каких либо проблем. Успехов вам в обучении

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

API_TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кнопка ссылка", callback_data="button_pressed")
    keyboard.add(button)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кнопки URL с переходом к шагу", reply_markup=keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button_pressed')
async def process_callback_button(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Вы нажали на кнопку!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду, то что кнопка перенаправляет на какой либо сайт к примеру:

ikb = InlineKeyboardButton(text = "Кнопка ссылка", url = "https://google.com")

как в таком случае оправить в чат сообщение "Вы нажали кнопку" ?

Comment: насколько я знаю в aiogram при использовании url в InlineKeyboardButton, невозможно обрабатывать callback_query одновременно.

Comment: Я наткнулся на данное короткое видео:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ue9XL5j4dA&ab_channel=BotHelp

Здесь это реализовано через какой-то конструктор, не могу понять как это можно сделать на питоне((

Comment: данный код не работает((